# mobx observable date field not rerender automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

If I'm not wrong the view should re-render whenever the date is changed but there seems to be a problem.
Am I missing any fundamental of mobx ? Or What I'm expecting is wrong?
It works for store but not for this date.

```
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';
import React from 'react';
import {observable,computed} from 'mobx';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Nav,Icon,Field,Control,Button, Hero, Container, Title, SubTitle, Tabs } from 'reactbulma'

@observer
class ExpenseListView extends React.Component {
@observable currDate = new Date();
constructor(){
    super();
}

render() {
    return (<div>
    <Hero dark>
      <Hero.Body>
        <Container hasTextCentered>
          <Title>  Expense List</Title>
            <SubTitle>
              <Button black small onClick={()=>{
                this.currDate.setDate(this.currDate.getDate() - 1);
                console.log(this.currDate);}}
                >
                {'<'}
                </Button>{this.currDate.toLocaleDateString()}
            </SubTitle>
        </Container>
      </Hero.Body>
    </Hero>
    </div>)

}
}
ReactDOM.render(<ExpenseListView />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I think you can use `observable.ref` instead of `observable` and re-assign new date to it on click. Then `currDate` will be changed (to a new ref) and it will be re-rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MobX can't handle `Date` objects in `observables` like that. You could e.g. store the locale date string in a string variable instead:

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vinisovawi/1/edit?js,output))**

```
@observer
class ExpenseListView extends React.Component {
  currDate = new Date();
  @observable currDateString = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

  handleClick = () => {
    this.currDate.setDate(this.currDate.getDate() - 1);
    this.currDateString = this.currDate.toLocaleDateString();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <button onClick={this.handleClick}> {'<'} </button>
         { this.currDateString }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimized solution. It seems I've solved it in hard way.